# Laravel 5 log data to another file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, monolog

Is there any way to log data into another file in laravel 5?
Not to standard one?
For examle i'd like to use something like this:

```
Log::info("Some log data", '/path/to/custom/file.log');
```

Or at least is there a possibility to divide log files basing on the log type.

```
Log::info("Some log data");
Log::error("Another log data");
```

So that info and error logs will go to different log files.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Here is example:

```
Log::useFiles(base_path() . '/path/to/custom/file.log', 'info');
Log::info('Do log this another PATH');
```

### Another way

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
$data = date('Y-m-d');
$time = date('h-A');
Log::useFiles(base_path() . '/log/'.$data.'/'.$time.'-'info.log', 'info');
Log::info('Do log this another PATH');
```

on this example every date create a folder with saperate log with hourly.

### Regarding Laravel 5:

You can also change single log path & name.

Add below line of code to :  `bootstrap>>app.php` `very bottom above of return $app`;

```php
    # SINGLE LOG
    $app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) use ($app) {
        $handler = new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($app->storagePath().'/logs/YOUR_SINGLE_LOG_NAME.log');
        $handler->setFormatter(new \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null, null, true, true));
        $monolog->pushHandler($handler);
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer the question? Only seems to show logging to one file.

Comment: Ok never mind that – I get it... but where would be a central place to set useFiles?

Comment: I want to write my information to this log file. but if after writing to this, all the other information will be written here too.

Answer (score 2):

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#configuration specifically **Custom Monolog Configuration** section.

Follow those directions to override default configuration then following these [directions to configure Monolog handlers](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/01-usage.md#configuring-a-logger).

Should be something like:

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) {
    $monolog->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(__DIR__.'/my_app.log', Logger::DEBUG));
});
```

Should get you in the right direction.